# Static variable in an inline method across compilation units

Tags: c++, templates, compilation, static, g++

Consider the following header file `Sample.h`:

```
#pragma once
template<typename T> class Sample {
  static T Method() {
    static T var = T(0);
    var++;
    return var;
  }
};
int U1Test();
int U2Test();
```

And 2 compilation units, `U1.cpp`:

```
#include "Sample.h"

int U1Test() { return Sample<int>::Method(); }
```

And `U2.cpp`:

```
#include "Sample.h"

int U2Test() { return Sample<int>::Method(); }
```

Then in another unit `Main.cpp`:

```
#include "Sample.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  cout << U1Test() << endl;
  cout << U2Test() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

When compiled, it gives me the following output:

```
1
2
```

But I'm not sure how the compiler does this, because the method is inline header-only and there is no compilation unit for it. So I would expect each compilation unit (like `U1.cpp` and `U2.cpp`) to receive its own copy of `var` because the method is inlined in that compilation unit.

Is there a subtle change that would make the variable separate in each compilation unit? I'm asking because code like this in a larger program seems to lead to crashes, so perhaps my reproducer is not enough (the reproducer works according to the C++ standard, AFAIK).

The compiler is `g++ (conda-forge gcc 10.3.0-16) 10.3.0` on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: *"I'm not sure how the compiler does this"*  We really don't have to know.  :-)  The rules say that whether a function is inlined or not must not affect its result. The rest is up to the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

> So I would expect each compilation unit (like U1.cpp and U2.cpp) to receive its own copy of var because the method is inlined in that compilation `unit`.

(The implicit) `inline` means that there may be multiple copies of the same function, but the linker will ignore all but one of them. Thus, all compilation units access that one function instantiation.

> Is there a subtle change that would make the variable separate in each compilation unit?

Yes, make the function (freestanding) `static` rather than (implicitly) `inline`:

```
static T Method() {
    static T var = T(0);
    var++;
    return var;
}
```

Note that this function is not in a class.